# How i scroll down left menu when we move bottom to page in bootstrap design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sir please help me to find a solution for bootstrap design.Ijust want when we scroll down page then left category menu also scroll down and when we move to upper side of page then it move to upper.here is my code

```
<div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian"><!--category-productsr-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordian" href="#hair">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                        Hindustan Unilever
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="hair" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="http://localhost/capital_product/productcat/food-brands">Food brands</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Homecare Brands</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Personal Care Brands</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Water Purifier Brand</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And this is my css for left sidebar

```
.category-products { border: 1px solid #F7F7F0;margin-bottom: 35px;margin-bottom: 35px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 15px;}.left-sidebar h2, .brands_products h2 {color: #4086c9;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;font-size: 18px; font-weight: 700; margin: 0 auto 30px;text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; position: relative;  z-index:3;}.left-sidebar h2:after, h2.title:after{content: " ";position: absolute;border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;bottom:8px;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 0;z-index: -2;}.left-sidebar h2:before{content: " ";position: absolute;background: #fff; bottom: -6px;width: 130px;height: 30px;z-index: -1;left: 50%;margin-left: -65px;}h2.title:before{content: " ";position: absolute;background: #fff;bottom: -6px;width: 220px;height: 30px;z-index: -1;left: 50%;margin-left: -110px;}
```

Comment: i just like to add functionality when i scroll down the page category also scroll down for ease to menu.

Comment: Can anyone reply me....i am very tense